# ADODB Recordset.RecordCount giving incorrect answer

Tags: vba, excel, adodb

I have an issue with my Recordset returning -1 as the RecordCount when in fact there are 1164 records.

I have checked my query which is fine. Even though it tells me there are -1 records the `CopyFromRecordset` method still works and pastes the correct results. Never had an issue before using the `rs.RecordCount`?

```
Dim strSQL As String
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

If cust = "JPM" Then
    port = "RP L99"
Else
    port = "RP V10"
End If

strSQL = "my select query"

rs.Open strSQL, cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
rs.MoveFirst
GetCompanies = rs.RecordCount
If GetCompanies > 0 Then
   wsLive.Range("A" & ROWCOMPANYSTART).CopyFromRecordset rs
   wsLive.Range("C" & ROWCOMPANYSTART & ":C" & GetCompanies + ROWCOMPANYSTART).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
End If
CloseRecordset rs

End Function
```

Comment: I'm surprised you never had this before - it's very common: http://www.w3schools.com/asp/prop_rs_recordcount.asp If you want to test if data was returned check that `rs.EOF` is false instead.

Comment: I actually want to know the number of records returned as well. Must have been lucky I guess! So how do you get the number of records then?

Comment: I rarely care how many records came back but I'd either check the size of the data range after using `CopyFromRecordset` or I'd dump the data into an array using `GetRows` so I can test the `Ubound` - but remember you need to transpose it to get it into the worksheet in the correct order.

Answer (score 2):

To get the actual count, you need to first move the cursor to the last record then move back to the beginning. However, remember for a large dataset, the moving back and forth will be an inefficient task. So, I would suggest the following with caution.

```
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

    If cust = "JPM" Then
        port = "RP L99"
    Else
        port = "RP V10"
    End If

    strSQL = "my select query"

    rs.CursorType = adOpenDynamic

    rs.Open strSQL, cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

    If Not (rs.BOF And rs.EOF) Then
        rs.MoveLast
        rs.MoveFirst
        GetCompanies = rs.RecordCount
        wsLive.Range("A" & ROWCOMPANYSTART).CopyFromRecordset rs
        wsLive.Range("C" & ROWCOMPANYSTART & ":C" & GetCompanies + ROWCOMPANYSTART).NumberFormat = "0.00%"      
    'Else
        'MsgBox "No Records !!"
    End If

    CloseRecordset rs
End Function
```

Comment: hi when it executes the rs.movelast I get a runtime error - "rowset does not support fetching backward"

Comment: In that case, you might need to specify the cursor movement. Try the edited code.

Comment: still get the same error message even after adding rs.CursorType = adOpenDynamic. Strange!