# Stored Procedure VB6 questino?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, vb6

I don't know if this question needs to be more in depth, but I think I have an issue with some of my code in VB6. I have a store procedure with 3 parameters. This is me executing it in VB6

```
g_strSQL = "exec sp_ClientSearchSelect @FirstName ='" & Me.txtFirst.Text & "', @LastName='" & Me.txtLast.Text & "', @DOB ='" & Me.mskDOB.Text & "'"
debug.print g_strSQL
```

When I run g_strSQL in SQL Server it pulls up the necessary information. This is the code that follows....

```
rS.Open g_strSQL, g_cnDatabase, adOpenStatic <--- Is this incorrect?

If rS.RecordCount > 0 Then <--- at this point, it shows that RECORDCOUNT is -1.
```

I don't want to include the whole SP because it's quite long. Basically what I'm doing with this SP is loading client info into a flex grid. The parameters I'm passing are included in my form, this is where user can search by firstname, lastname or DOB, however, on form load the grid should load with all client info --then user can search by name. In this case, the grid doesn't load but when I execute the SP in server, it loads all the info. If this information is not sufficient enough, then I apologize.

Comment: Typically the only SQL statements you *open* contain a `SELECT`; all others use `Execute`.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the recordcount may not be populated until you iterate the whole recordset, so try iterating "while not rs.eof ... rs.movenext" and take the record count after the end of the loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB6 ADODB.Recordset RecordCount property always returns -1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282661/vb6-adodb-recordset-recordcount-property-always-returns-1), and [ADODB Recordset.RecordCount giving incorrect answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30169900/adodb-recordset-recordcount-giving-incorrect-answer), and probably a few more. Rather than going to the last record, try replacing 'adOpenStatic' with  'adOpenDynamic'.

Comment: @C-PoundGuru thanks for the links. I included rS.CursorLocation = adUseClient before g_strSQL and it loaded everything okay.

Comment: Thank You all for your help!